# hide galleryView plugin without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jquery in my page to load the content without refreshing, and only show what is needed. In the gallery div I have an "Other Photography" and "Nude Art" link. By clicking on each of this it will initialize the gallery with the given pictures. However once I initalized one of them, there is no way to hide it to create room for the other one.

I made 2 ul li lists with the images with the same id for the css, but with different classes, that's how I am trying to distinguish them...

```
<div id="underage">
  <ul class="galleryShow">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="adult">
  <ul class="galleryShow">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And this is the Jquery**

```
$('#galleryButton').click(function() {
                $('.mainBody').slideUp().ready(function() {
                    $('#gallery').slideDown(600).ready(function() {

                            $('#otherPhotoButton').click(function() {
                                /*$('.adult').hide();*/
                                $('.underage').galleryView();
                            });

                            $("#nudeButton").confirm({
                                text: "Are you over 18?",
                                confirm: function(button) {
                                    /*$('.undergage').hide();*/
                                    $('.adult').galleryView();
                                },
                                cancel: function(button) {
                                    window.location.href = "https://www.google.hu/search?q=puppies";
                                },
                                confirmButton: "Yes I am",
                                cancelButton: "No"
                            });
                        });     
                    }); 
                });
```

Comment: You have two elements with an ID of `galleryShow`. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Yes thank you! I have changed that, however the problem is still not solved :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather irritatingly, the GalleryView plugin does not seem to keep the ID on elements you apply it to.

To remedy this, change your HTML a bit:

```
<div id="underage">
    <ul class="galleryShow">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="adult">
    <ul class="galleryShow">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is some JavaScript for your buttons that should work:

```js
$('#otherPhotoButton').click(function() {
    if ($('#underage ul').length) {
        $('#underage ul').galleryView();
    }
    $('#underage').show();
    $('#adult').hide();
});
$('#nudeButton').confirm({
    text: 'Are you over 18?',
    confirm: function(button) {
        if ($('#adult ul').length) {
            $('#adult ul').galleryView();
        }
        $('#adult').show();
        $('#underage').hide();
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.hu/search?q=puppies';
    },
    confirmButton: 'Yes, I am',
    cancelButton: 'No'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your answer led me to the solution. I had to change it a little bit to get it work. I am posting the solution right now!

Comment: Yeah, I messed up my code slightly; I didn't test it. It's definitely the `ul` that needs to be passed to galleryView. Editing. The `.length` check is to prevent possible errors if galleryView doesn't already do this check internally.

Comment: I am kind of new to JavaScript or Jquery, this is my first real project, can you explain to me what exactly the if `($('#adult ul').length)` does? When will that be true or false? Thanks and sorry for the noob question

Comment: No problem. The if statement will return true if any `#adult ul` elements exist. If there are no JavaScript errors without the `.length` check, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use duplicate ids, change your class and id tags values for both your `<ul>` tags so they read

```
<ul id="underage" class='galleryShow'>
<ul id="adult" class='galleryShow'>
```

and change all the css in #galleryShow to .galleryShow.

The library you are using galleryView may be changing the markup after it is initialized so please post a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do that, right now the site seems to be down... But I'll post it